# gulp-notify error; No reporter specified

Tags: node.js, vagrant, gulp, gulp-less

I am developing a Magento website using Vagrant and Puppet to manage my dev environment.

I am using the Magento Boilerplate theme (https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate) as a base, which uses Gulp.js to run automatic compilation of LESS and JS files.

I am running gulp from the host machine as this has the full suite of node, npm, etc installed, but I get the following error:

```
stream.js:94
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
[gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify': No reporter specified.
```

The host machine is Ubuntu 12.04 and the Guest is CentOS. The host has the required notify-send package installed and the guest has libnotify, but gulp does not seem to recognise either.

I am new to gulp having used Grunt in the past, so may be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

`gulp-notify` is intended to be run on a desktop environment, with a notifier.  It makes no sense to have it on a headless server.

You can use [the `gulp-if` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-if/) and [the `gulp-util` library](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-util)  along with a production / development flag to prevent `gulp-notify` from being run on the server.

Set it up like so:

```js
var _if = require('gulp-if'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

var production = gutil.env.production;

//...

     // use like so in your pipe:
    .pipe(_if(!production, notify('...')))
```

Then, run it like this on your server:

```bash
gulp --production
```

If you'd prefer to be cautious, you can reverse it so that you test for `--dev` (`gutil.env.dev`) and only enable it when that is true.

Comment: Thanks @OverZealous, if nothing else I like the way you handle environments there.
However, to respond to your opening comment I am running the grunt task from my desktop, not the VM as Vagrant has created synced folders.
If I take out all the gulp-notify references the gulp tasks run fine. It just doesn't seem capable of recognising my install of notify-send.

Comment: I've never tested gulp-notify on vagrant, but there is an blogpost on using it here: jpbetley.com/vagrant-gulp-notifications